# Databinding an array of objects?

Tags: arrays, xaml, windows-phone-7, data-binding

As an intern i need to develop an WP7 app and i am in a learning stage now to figure out and learn WP7. N
ow i've run into databinding for windows phone 7. Allready i know this will be one of the most important features i'll be using for this app.

So i'm getting an array of objects A which has an object B and object B has an object C.
What i'd like to have is databind the array, then for each object A in the array it will show data for the object and objects B,C which object A has.

Is such a thing possible with xaml? If so does anyone has an example for that.

Please bear in mind i'm totally new in silverlight/xaml/wp7 and trying to learn as much as possible in limited time. I am searching the web for this alot and havent (yet) found an awner. Hoping someone here can clear things up for me.

Answer (score 1):

As for databindings, [read a tutorial](http://www.wpftutorial.net/DataBindingOverview.html).

For the actual presentation, decide on a UI element. If you do nested lists, you'll just bind to the property of the parent element.